# clicking on test ads(banner or interstitial) crashes android app

Tags: android, admob

I have added Admob banner and interstitial ads in my application(at different places). To test if the ads work fine I added my test deviceId while making ad request as below,

```
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("*********...").build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

The test ads are coming as expected, however when I click on the test ads, it crashes the application. Is it normal?

The error log, although in similar line, changes slightly(the activity name) with the change in the test ads, as below,

```
        android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.mobeam.barcodeService/com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
        08-25 17:10:58.276: W/System.err(27595):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1648)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1442)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3511)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3472)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3714)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3682)
        at agl.startActivity(SourceFile:71)
        at acl.a(SourceFile:120)
        at agm.a(SourceFile:233)
        at agm.a(SourceFile:165)
        at abl.a(SourceFile:102)
        at agm.a(SourceFile:377)
        at agm.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(SourceFile:293)
        at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebViewContentsClientAdapter.java:293)
        at com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.AwContentsClientBridge.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(AwContentsClientBridge.java:96)
        at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
        at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:27)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am using new Admob and the app is signed using debug key. Can I assume that in release mode it will work as expected? if not then how to fix this?

Comment: Post your AndroidManifest.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have declared this in your AndroidManfiest.xml

```
<activity
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
```

Then you should be able to click on the ad and it shouldn't crash.

Comment: can you post part of your androidManifest?

Comment: items related to admob are, <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" /> and <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" /> I am sure I have followed the Admob documentation. The ads appear but as I mentioned when I click on the test ads the app crashes.

Comment: did you click the export check box in the order/export tab?

Comment: you will typically export when you want to sign the app using release key. The trouble here is that when the app is signed using debug key the test ads crashes the app on click on them. But when the app is signed using release key, the normal ads do not crash the app on click on them. I guess I will live with this for the time being. But the questions remains open is crashing of app in debug mode when test ad is clicked.